# Subtracting Row 2 from Row 1 in a Tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I have a tibble object in R, which looks like the following:
[image]

For each column, I want to subtract row1 from row2. My current approach is below:

```
mean.diff <- each.group.mean[1,2:num.groups]-each.group.mean[2,2:num.centroids]
```

What is confusing is that to execute this statement on the 2x9660 tibble, the code takes 8-15 secs, as determined by a Sys.time() calculation. Would appreciate any help to make this faster and to understand why this command takes so long.

Comment: How about `unlist` it and substract ie. `unlist(each.group.mean[1,2:num.groups], use.names = FALSE)-unlist(each.group.mean[2,2:num.centroids], use.names = FALSE)`  A `tibble` or `data.frame` etc have additional class attributes which makes it slower.  So, the best option may be to `unlist` to a `vector` and then do the subtraction on two vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `unlist`ing, we could convert this to a `vector` and make it more efficient

```
unlist(each.group.mean[1,2:num.groups], use.names = FALSE)-
    unlist(each.group.mean[2,2:num.centroids], use.names = FALSE)
```

The reason is that a `data.frame` or `tibble` etc have many class attributes that makes it slower to do the subset and then the computation.  By converting to `vector` all those classes are stripped off.  Using a reproducible example

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.tibble(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 9660*10, 
     replace = TRUE), ncol = 9660)))
```

#### Benchmarks

```
system.time(df1[1,] - df1[2,])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.78    0.00    0.78 

system.time(unlist(df1[1,], use.names = FALSE) - unlist(df1[2,], use.names = FALSE))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.03    0.00    0.03
```